# Symfony2 TinymceBundle - CTRL-S does not save after update

Tags: php, symfony, tinymce

I'm working on a PHP-web application, which uses the TinymceBundle to style the textboxes as WYSIWYG-Editors (I took over that project, I didn't implement this feature initially).

Apparently the tinyMCE Editor by standard has a build in feature that captures the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> Click event and treats it as form submission (instead of the browser trying to save the current site).

But now I did an update of the vendor libraries, including TinymceBundle and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the form doesn't work anymore.

This is the configuration of the widget in `app/config.yml` how I found it:

```
stfalcon_tinymce:
    include_jquery: true
    textarea_class: "tinymce"
    theme:
        simple:
            mode: "textareas"
            theme: "advanced"
            width: '728' #firefox on windows made it too wide for some reason
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "mylistbox,mysplitbutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink"
            theme_advanced_buttons2: ""
            theme_advanced_buttons3: ""
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top"
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left"
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom"
            plugins: "fullscreen"
            theme_advanced_buttons1_add: "fullscreen"
        advanced:
            language: de
            theme: "advanced"
            plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template"
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect"
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor"
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen"
            theme_advanced_buttons4: "moveforward,movebackward,|,scite,del,ins,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak"
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top"
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left"
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom"
            theme_advanced_resizing: true
```

for what I can see, there is nothing specifically enabling the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> save functionality, so I assumed it is enabled by default, but now I need something to enable it again (as the customer is missing it since the update) and I didn't find a config option for this at the [tinyMCE documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration).

Staying with the old version is not really an option.

Does anybody know how to enable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> = form submit functionality by hand **or** did also experience this behavior after an update of TinymceBundle (if it's a bug of tinyMCE I can't do much I guess)?

**Edit:** the following is the code used in the application to render the editor - unfortunately nearly everything of the JS-initialization is encapsulated in the `TinymceBundle`, even the `tinyMCE.init( ... )` call - the whole configuration is supposed to work over the entries in the `app/config.ym`.

The `NoticeType` class that has the text field:

```
class NoticeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('contact')
        ->add('user')
        ->add('direction', 'choice', array(
                        'choices'   => array('out' => 'Ausgehend', 'in' => 'Eingehend', ),
                        'required'  => true,
        ))
        ->add('text', 'textarea', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce'),
        ))
        ->add('customer')
        ->add('date', 'datetime', array(
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                // 'date_format' => \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
                'widget' => 'single_text',
        ))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'evenos_enoticebundle_noticetype';
    }
}
```

in the template where the form is rendered:

```
{% extends 'EvenosEnoticeBundle::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Neue Notiz</h1>
{{ tinymce_init() }}
<form action="{{ path('notice_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    [...other fields...]
    {{ form_label(form.text, 'Text') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.text, { 'attr': {'cols': '100', 'rows': 20} }) }}
    [...]
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btnCreate">Anlegen</button>
    </p>
</form>

[...]

{% endblock %}
```

**Updated Question:** Does somebody know how I can configure tinyMCE **specifically using `Stfalcon/TinymceBundle` for `Symfony2`?**. As I grasp it, it es meant to only be configured through symfony `.yml` files, which don't let you add e.g. functions like the

```
setup: function (ed) { ... }
```

configuration for tinyMCE

Comment: i am facing same problem  here!!could you found the soln for this in symfony2 !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement something like i advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965490/disabling-tinymce-ctrls-shortcut-to-enable-this-shortcut-for-ajax-content-save) for a similar problem.

**EDIT**: Here is an excellent tutorial for [symfone/tinymce](http://symfony-world.blogspot.de/2010/03/using-tinymce-with-symfony.html). In the section "Override the render method" you insert a setup configuration parameter as follows

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...

    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onKeyDown.add(function onkeydown(ed, evt) {
            // Shortcut:  ctrl+h 
            if (evt.keyCode == 72 && !evt.altKey && !evt.shiftKey && evt.ctrlKey && !evt.metaKey) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var e = { type : 'keydown'};
                    e.charCode = e.keyCode = e.which = 72;
                    e.shiftKey = e.altKey = e.metaKey = false;
                    e.ctrlKey = true;
                    window.parent && window.parent.receiveShortCutEvent && window.parent.receiveShortCutEvent(e);
                }, 1);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Now you insert the script tag containing the javascript function `receive_shortcutevents` in the template.

Comment: Well I hoped there would be a more "standard" way to do this - but appareantly I need to do it with a hack (at least feels that way). I'll wait some more days for other suggestions, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: unfortunatly, there seems to be no other way (or i would have used it myself)

Comment: unfortunately I'm using tinyMCE as a bundle for Symfony2 the only place where I think I can define some callback functions is the config.yml file I posted in my question - do you have some experience with tinyMCE in Symfony2? I currently can't figure out how to use the answer you linked in my situation.

Comment: I had some experience with Symfony some time ago, but not with both in combination. Can you locate the piece of code that will render your html (and javascript) ?

Comment: I added what I found in the application of tinyMCE being used to the question, but I don't know how much it helps. The rest is burried in the TinymceBundle vendor library

Comment: well, you will need to add the function receiveShortCutEvent in a script tag in the template head

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to actually hook that function into the editor, so that it gets called on CTRL+S. I understand that's more of a problem of how to configure the `TinymceBundle` for symfony than a problem of the tinyMCE editor itself ..

Comment: unfortunately, that tutorial is for symfony 1X, not 2X, wich are quite different :/ as I said, I don't really find where I can even get to modify the `tinyMCE.init()` call, as it is burried somewhere in the bundle, all I have in the application is the twig `tinymce_init()` call, whose definition is also buried somewhere down there ... I'll update my question to ask specifically about TinymceBundle for Symfony2

Comment: I accepted this answer now since it suited the original question as I wrote it :)